# Writing a Script to execute commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, executable

I have never written a script, so bear with me. What I need to do, is make two scripts that I can click on from the desktop, will both open their own terminal (And stay open until I manually close it) and run the given lines.
For the first one, I have to manually run this:

```
cd home/pi/PiBits/ServoBlaster/user
sudo ./servod
```

For the second:

```
cd ~/scratchClient
python crs/scratchClient.py -c servoblaster
```

How would I do this? I read a few things about putting `xterm -e` and such in front of it, but none of that works for me...
By the way, this will be used on Raspbian Linux.
EDIT, this worked for me:
Link: ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1336228 The line that was used: gnome-terminal `--execute bash -c "/path/scriptname ; bash"`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a shebang, which means putting this in the first line of the script:

`#!/bin/sh`

This causes the bourne shell to be used to interpret the script, this is (probably) the same interpreter that runs when you are in your terminal. Then you should make the script executable `chmod +x <script>`

Comment: `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh, not bash; thus, describing it as the "Bourne (Again) Shell" is inappropriate. Even when `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`, it disables features for POSIX compatibility.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't be surprised if the OP's problem has something to do with `sudo` refusing to work when stdin isn't connected to a terminal (by default; configurable via `/etc/sudoers`).

Comment: Sudo would be an issue, yes. I always run both of these in a root terminal, and so i don't have to enter it. The Servoblaster Definitely needs sudo, i don't know about the python script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
xterm -hold -e 'cd /home/pi/PiBits/ServoBlaster/user
    sudo ./servod' &
```

and

```
xterm -hold -e 'cd /home/pi/scratchClient
    python crs/scratchClient.py -c servoblaster' &
```

If it doesn't work, perhaps you should explain in what way this fails. If it works, you can add a shebang in front, save them in files, `chmod +x` those files, and click away to your heart's content (or perhaps acquire a more sophisticated taste where you simply run these as background jobs without any `xterm` or other anxious GUI).

Comment: I'll try them in a bit, and i'll let you know. Acquire a more sophisticated taste? Lols.
Reason i need them visible is because currently, its all quite buggy. Scratchclient tends to crash often, or even disconnect from scratch and servoblaster entirely. When one of these events happens, it notifies me in the active terminal. It helps a lot with debugging, see that it was scratchlient that crashed, or that servoblaster is getting invalid dimensions, and so on.

Comment: It runs, but instantly closes. No errors, makes me assume it runs in the background. How would i keep the session open? And do i click `Execute` or `Execute in Terminal`?

Comment: And do i name it `name` or `name.sh`?

Comment: I added `-hold` which seems to work... I think i might stick with this.

Comment: Big issue, Scratchclient isn't detecting Servoblaster as running. Could it be that the servoblaster script doesn't actually run it properly?

Comment: Ok, so the python script works, but the servoblaster one doesn't. Not correctly at least. If i manually run servoblaster (Enter it all in in a separate terminal) then it all works. I actually don't really need the servoblaster script to stay open, and so i won't put `-hold` on that one. (Works very well on the other) How would i get it working?

Comment: Then don't run the servoblaster in an `xterm` at all -- just do `( cd /wherever; command & )`.  It's not clear from your description which one isn't working -- the Python script or the `servod`?  I would assume you mean the latter, which however probably does not need to run in a separate terminal (and if you are already `root` you would not need `sudo`; however, running a GUI as `root` is extremely foolish).

Comment: It doesn't matter what you call the files, as long as they have a proper shebang and executable mode (but don't use a name which is already taken, for your own sanity).

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use gnome-terminal... Found [an UbuntuForums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1336228) with a similar question such as mine.

```
gnome-terminal --execute bash -c "/path/scriptname ; bash"
```

Comment: Link please? Try to help future visitors with the same problem.

Comment: Link: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1336228
The line that was used:
    `gnome-terminal --execute bash -c "/path/scriptname ; bash"`

Comment: Please edit your answer to include this information, and accept the answer so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved. Thanks.

Comment: Uh, I still haven't figured out how to do that last bit... :!

Comment: [The edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28609889/edit) just below your answer. Then click the big friendly checkmark on the left so it's filled instead of hollow. See [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for details.